# Node class- am I going crazy?

Tags: c++

I have a node class which gives me the following compiler error on a simple header declaration. I really cannot see why its being caused?!

```
1> Node.h(4): error : invalid redeclaration of type name "Node" (declared at line 4)
1>    class Node{
1>          ^
```

Header:

```
using namespace std;

class Node{     //THIS IS LINE 4 

    public:
        Node(int val);
        int val;
        Node* l_node;
        Node* r_node;

    private:

};
```

Source:

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(int x) : l_node(nullptr), r_node(nullptr), val(x){

}
```

Do I need a forward declaration or something???

Comment: You need include guard

Comment: @billz Put it as an answer and i'll accept- you were right.

Comment: @g-makulik Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @user997112 no need to, he's wrong. C++ allows what you're doing regarding using `Node*` within class `Node`. And a different note, get this: `using namespace std;` **out** of your header file. If you need standard library types in your headers, fully qualify them via `std::`. Make it a habit now, because I can assure you it will bite you sooner or later if you don't.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks craig for the std tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a header file, always remember to write an include guard.

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node{      

public:
    explicit Node(int val); // add explicit to disable implicit conversion
    int val;
    Node* l_node;
    Node* r_node; 
};
#endif
```

Also, do **NOT** use `using` directives in header file; it's bad practice.

And in constructors, beware of member initialization order. Initialize members in declaration order, otherwise you might get caught by an initialize order issue:

```
Node::Node(int x) : val(x), l_node(nullptr), r_node(nullptr){

}
```

Comment: Also, most compilers support `#pragma once` at the beginning of file instead of the one with definitions. First one is said to be more efficient but I don't know how much it differs.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from include guards, you should almost always create a corresponding .cpp file for every header, and put the implementation there. If you have multiple libs using the same header, and they get linked in together by a third program, it will produce linker errors. Include guards won't protect you against this scenario.